# Python try and except in launching password less ssh connection

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I want to know whether this scenario of taking ssh works or not with try and except. If try part ask for the ssh password then it should move to except part. Here is my code,

```
 import os,sys,subprocess

         def ProcesS (input):
            print input
            A = subprocess.Popen (input,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            output,error = A.communicate()
            return output,error

 try:
         ProcesS('ssh system1@123.123.123.123 \'ls\'')
 except:
         ProcesS('ssh system2@10.101.10.1 \'ssh system1@123.123.123.123 \'ls\' \'')
```

In my case this is not even working at the ssh time out.

Comment: Just as an aside, you should *really* not use a bare `except` clause: that catches *everything*, even things like ctrl-c to abort. Just catch the exceptions you actually expect.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote it it won't, because `ssh` will sit there waiting for password and not fail.

However since you are not sending any input to the command, you can pass the `-n` option to `ssh` and it will fail if it wanted to ask anything. So with `-n` it should work.